# Sequence not convergent in $\ell^2$ but convergent in $\ell^p$ with $p>2$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

Let $\{v_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \ell^2$ be a sequence of $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\|v_m\|_2 \to \infty$ ($\ell^2$ norm) and $\forall p>2: \lim_{m \to \infty} \|v_m\|_p < \infty$

Is it true that:
$\lim_{m \to \infty} \|v_m - v_{m+1}\|_2 = 0$

Thanks.

Comment: Source of this question, please?

Comment: it would be useful to solve a problem of mine.. if it was true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Define $v_n$ by
$$
v_{n,k} = \begin{cases} 
\frac1{ \sqrt{k-n^2}} & \text{ if } k \in \{ (n^2+1)\dots (n+1)^2\}\\
0 & \text{ else.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\|v_n\|_2^2$ contains the first $2n+1$ addends of the harmonic series. In addition the $(v_n)$ are pairwise orthogonal. 
And for $p>2$
$$
\|v_n\|_p^p \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-p/2} < +\infty
$$

Comment: thanks for your answer